# why does function work on element but not array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm getting confused about when I can apply a function to an array element but not to the entire array.  For exapmle:

I have a dataframe of time stamps where I'd just like to get the unique dates and day of weeks into a dataframe.  Pulling the dates out is pretty easy:

```
dates_only = df.dtime.dt.date.unique()
```

at that point:

```
print type(dates_only)           -> <type 'numpy.ndarray'> 
print type(dates_only[0])        -> <type 'datetime.date'>
print dates_only[0].weekday()    -> 4
```

but I can't create a new series by applying the weekday function:

```
dow = dates_only.weekday() 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-76986b9b07a2> in <module>()
----> 4 dow = dates_only.weekday()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Do I need to cast the ndarray somehow or should I be processing these in a loop like:

```
for i in range(len(dates_only)):
    dow[i] = dates_only[i].weekday()
```

I think it will work but it just seems so wrong...

Thanks for looking!

Comment: In general, python functions are *not* vectorized. Vectorization is a feature of `numpy` and numpy-related libraries (e.g. `pandas`). As Jezrael pointed out, this particular feature has been implemented in a vectorized way in `pandas` but if it hadn't, you would have to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `unique` return `numpy array`, but you can convert it to [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) and then use [`DatetimeIndex.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html), last use `Series` constructor:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (df)
   a      dtime
0  0 2015-02-24
1  1 2015-02-25
2  2 2015-02-26
3  3 2015-02-27
4  4 2015-02-28
5  5 2015-03-01
6  6 2015-03-02
7  7 2015-03-03
8  8 2015-03-04
9  9 2015-03-05
```

```
dates_only = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.dtime.dt.date.unique())

dow = dates_only.weekday
print (dow)
[1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3]

dow = pd.Series(dates_only.weekday, index=df.index)
print (dow)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    0
7    1
8    2
9    3
dtype: int32
```

Another solution is convert `numpy array` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use `Series` constructor:

```
dates_only = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.dtime.dt.date.unique()), index=df.index)
print (dates_only)

dow = dates_only.dt.weekday
print (dow)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    0
7    1
8    2
9    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That works great.  I still don't get why I can process entire arrays or elements with a single function sometimes but not others, but that fixes my immediate problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of time objects.

And time objects have that method week_day():

```
print dates_only[0].weekday()    -> 4
```

But that doesn't turn that ARRAY of time objects into a time object!

In other words: when you have a box of apples, does that mean you can eat the box itself?

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) for potential solutions.

Comment: Got it.  You're  saying there is no way to apply object functions to an array of such objects.

Comment: Exactly. And the other answers tell you how to collect the data you are looking for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not handle an array like this. You have to loop over the array as you wrote (does not look wrong to me) or use map:

```
dow = map(lambda date: date.weekday(), dates_only)
```

Comment: y, that rocks!  That's what I was looking for.